# getting current location with LocationManager

Tags: codenameone, locationmanager

I'd like to get user current location with my codenameone android application. But this seems to take too much time. Timeout is set to 20000 and I find it too long. Is there a way to detect location with a reduced timeout? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Timeout is just a way to tell your app to stop searching for location at a specified time if not found. Location can be found within a second or two if GPS is turned on and a user is not underground.

Comment: And play services is enabled ;-)